# Converting a dataframe from a matrix format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    1    2    3
1   1    4    2
2   4    1    8
3   2    8    1
```

I am trying to convert it to a dataframe with this format:

```
Comparison  Value
1 v 1       1
1 v 2       4
1 v 3       2
2 v 3       8
```

Reproducible dataframe:

```
{1: {1: 1.0, 2: 4, 3: 2}, 2: {1: 4, 2: 1.0, 3: 8}, 3: {1: 2, 2: 8, 3: 1.0}}
```

Comment: Should  this `1 v 1` be a string value?

Comment: Shall we assume that the dataframe is a symmetrical square matrix? What is the objective, you put an example but not a description of the format that you are trying to achieve. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({1: {1: 1.0, 2: 4, 3: 2}, 2: {1: 4, 2: 1.0, 3: 8}, 3: {1: 2, 2: 8, 3: 1.0}})

# dictionary to hold new "matrix" format
matdata = {"Comparison": [], "Value": []}

# loop over rows and columns
for i in range(1, 4):
    for j in range(1, 4):
        matdata["Comparison"].append(f"{i} v {j}")
        matdata["Value"].append(df.loc[i, j])

newdf = pd.DataFrame(matdata)

print(newdf)

  Comparison  Value
0      1 v 1    1.0
1      1 v 2    4.0
2      1 v 3    2.0
3      2 v 1    4.0
4      2 v 2    1.0
5      2 v 3    8.0
6      3 v 1    2.0
7      3 v 2    8.0
8      3 v 3    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following simple approach with [`pandas.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
pd.DataFrame([(f'{c} v {i}', df.at[i, c]) for c in df.columns for i in df.index], 
              columns=['Comparison', 'Value'])
```

---

```
  Comparison  Value
0      1 v 1    1.0
1      1 v 2    4.0
2      1 v 3    2.0
3      2 v 1    4.0
4      2 v 2    1.0
5      2 v 3    8.0
6      3 v 1    2.0
7      3 v 2    8.0
8      3 v 3    1.0
```